# Entendendo teste do RegEx no MDN

Tags: regex

Olá, pesquisando sobre Expressão Regular, peguei um link para o MDN: [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test, mas olhei, olhei e não entendi porque o exemplo testou duas vezes cada variável, e porque o último teste retornou false. A parte do exemplo dado, o qual preciso compreender é:

```
var regex1 = RegExp('foo*');

var regex2 = RegExp('foo*','g');

var str1 = 'table football';

console.log(regex1.test(str1));

// expected output: true

console.log(regex1.test(str1));      // porque testar de novo?

// expected output: true

console.log(regex2.test(str1));

// expected output: true

console.log(regex2.test(str1));      // por que testar de novo e por que retornou false?

// expected output: false
```

Comment: A flag `g`lobal serve para que o ponteiro avance a cada busca. Se você procurar "X" em "AXBXCXDEFG" vai retornar true, true, true, false pq acha 3 vezes o valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A explicação está lá:

> Using test() on a regex with the global flag
>
> If the regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the lastIndex of the regex. A subsequent use of test() will start the search at the substring of str specified by lastIndex (exec() will also advance the lastIndex property). It is worth noting that the lastIndex will not reset when testing a different string.

O que isto significa ? Que quando não é usado o flag "g" é possível repetir o teste que o resultado é sempre o mesmo. Mas quando se usa o flag "g" um segundo teste pode dar um resultado diferente do primeiro teste, porque o segundo teste vai pular a parte da string que já foi analisada no primeiro teste. Por isso a repetição dos testes no site.

Comment: Ótimo, lamento não ter simplesmente lido mais um pouco o artigo do MDN. Realmente... está lá! Grato.